# NodeJS redirect to valid route throwing error with NodeError:invalid status code

Tags: node.js, express

My Node application requires a specific `session` token/field to be set to perform a setup.

The issue with this and other `authentication` type methods is any redirect outside of my router files seems to fail with the same reason.

**Example Code (mcve)** (you will need [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) [setup](https://github.com/expressjs/session) for this)

1. create file `auth.js`
2. add the function and export it:

   ```
   const checkAdminAuthenticatedSetup = () => (req, res, next) => {
       if(req.session.authenticated !== true) {
           return res.status(302).redirect('/setup/auth', {message: "Please enter password to continue setup"})
       } else {
           next();
       } 
   }

   module.exports = {
       checkAdminAuthenticatedSetup
   }
   ```
3. in your router file, `const auth = require("auth")`
4. for some route, do the following:

   ```
   router.get('/financial',
       auth.checkAdminAuthenticatedSetup(),        <---------- this line should check if there is a req.session.authenticated (= true) value, else redirect to another page /setup/auth
       function (req, res, next) {
            res.render("setup-banking-information");
       });
   ```

**The problem**

this redirect "fails" with the following message:

```
>>> console.log(err)
NodeError: Invalid status code: [object Object] at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:209:11) at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26) at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26) at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:200:8) at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:585:9) at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:702:5) at ServerResponse.end (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express-session\index.js:355:19) at ServerResponse.redirect (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:947:10) at C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\utils\auth.js:30:32 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at next (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13) at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22 at Function.process_params (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12) at next (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) at Function.handle (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3) at router (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at trim_prefix (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13) at C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7 at Function.process_params (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
stack = "RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: [object Object]\n at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:209:11)\n at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)\n at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)\n at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:200:8)\n at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:585:9)\n at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:702:5)\n at ServerResponse.end (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express-session\index.js:355:19)\n at ServerResponse.redirect (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:947:10)\n at C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\utils\auth.js:30:32\n at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\CybeX\WebstormProjects\awesome-app\node_modules\express\lib\ro"… (length: 2,501)
message = "Invalid status code: [object Object]"
__proto__ = RangeError {constructor: , name: , code: }
[[StableObjectId]] = 3
```

Each time this redirect happens (outside of a router file), this method (inside `app.js`) gets hit

```
// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});
```

Further, something I noticed is after "rendering" the `error.pug` page, the browser simply hangs on the page it attempted to load initially and does NOT render the `error` page in the browser, the browser simply loads forever.

Answer (score 0):

*Asked and answered. This is a simple oversight.*

Express does not allow parsing additional information via the [redirect method](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) such as (in my case) the additional parameter for rendering the page `{ message: "..."}`

**Format/Syntax for `redirect()` is:**

```
res.redirect([status,] path)
```

In my case, I should add this as a flash message.